# Using FastLane to automate an iOS App

Tags: ios, react-native, build, fastlane

I'm trying to understand if there is ANY possible way to automate the deployment for an iOS App with Fastlane. My doubts are:

1. Can Fastlane build my iOS app if my commands are running in a Linux Server without XCode?
2. Is there any way that I can achieve Fastlane to build my iOS app without XCode?
3. Is there any App or something that allow the automation of deploying Apps to Apple Store from your React-Native code or APK?

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 3):

Let me quickly answer you:

1. No
2. No
3. There is a cloud base solution for that purpose: https://www.bitrise.io

If there is anything else I can help with or explain more further just shoot :)

Comment: Ah, you're definitely right! What I had in my mind was that he really needs a machine with Xcode in order to build his app for auto deployment, what he would like to bypass somehow :)

Comment: Yes, you right. I know I can use Fastlane to submit the App to App Store. What I want to know is if there is any way to automate this process from a Linux server. I'll check bitrise.io, thanks @Ivan